# How to crop a SVG image to the bounding box of the vector grafics elements

Tags: svg, png, command-line-tool, librsvg, rsvg

I have a SVG image here[image] which is generated with 'empty space', i.e. only in the top-left corner is image content, whereas the rest is blank. I think it should be *trivially possible* to have an automated way to crop the image size to the bounding box of the objects - at least for some svg tooling like rsvg. However I am unable to find the 'command line trick' for this, etc.

I would like to do this on the command line (i.e. as part of a build script)

In principle I would be interested in a solution to the same problem but for pixel-based formats such as PNG as well.

Answer (score 2):

rsvg does not have command line utilities for this problem, but [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org) in its non-GUI mode has:

```
inkscape -o cropped.svg -D source.svg
```

will crop the file to the bounding box of all objects of the document. See the [man page](https://inkscape.org/doc/inkscape-man.html) for a full documentation of the inkscape command line options. Especially note the `--shell` mode for batch processing multiple images.

For pixel-based formats there is the [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org) [`-trim`](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#trim) option:

```
convert source.png -trim +repage cropped.png
```